# Best GUI concept to edit/manage large acyclic graphs

Tags: user-interface, graph

The point is to enable fast and intuitive management of potentially large graph structures

Concepts I've come across are:

- Tree
- TreeMap
- Venn diagram
- Hyperbolic tree

Which one would you prefer or other ideas?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Hyperbolic Trees are a patented idea (by Xerox). If you're building a comercial system, you may want to stay away from this one.

Comment: No immediate plans for anything commercial but thanks! Unrelated though - with IBM alone filing for 4000 patents last year I'm not surprised :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practical UI solution I have come across for large graphs is [Mark Shepherd's spring graph](http://web.archive.org/web/20120103172324/http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/springgraph-flex-component).  It scales quite well too.

Comment: Excellent solution - not sure how it lends itself to editing though.

Comment: What sort of editing?  If you have a full CRUD cycle you'll have to write the code yourself.  If you mean editing properties of the objects behind the nodes, ditto.  If you mean rearranging the nodes and stroing the presentation then that can be done too - probably by extending your domain model.

Comment: @Simon the link is dead could you link to another?

Comment: let me just google that for you...
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1048510#

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at GUESS which has some nice rapid prototyping features like an integrated domain specific language for graph manipulation/generation and includes a variety of graph layouts. Which means you can easily hack a demo and check if you like the interface.

http://graphexploration.cond.org/

Answer (score 1):

Here some clever ideas for different scales:

1. [Zircle UI](https://zircleui.github.io/zircleUI/#/) A real cool vuejs component, navigation feels a bit like zooming through mandelbrot fractals. atm limited by six levels.
2. [Tree Browser with D3](https://github.com/unused/hyperbolic-tree-browser) Smart solution by TU Graz. Not sure about licensing impact, but looks really promising.
3. [gephi](https://gephi.org/) This will be used by data journalist to show very large plots, but is not the most interactive solution.
4. [yed/yworks](https://www.yworks.com/) Very experienced company with a wide range of awesome diagramming solutions
5. [GraphQLViz](https://github.com/Macroz/GraphQLviz) Space Hot Rod for Graphviz.

Why not using a mindmap solution? There are soo many cool out there. For e.g.

1. [mindmeister](https://www.mindmeister.com)  Great Web-Solution, where you can easy share your work like a google document.
2. [simplemind](https://simplemind.eu/) As App or PC. My personal fav esp on my handy. There is also a free edition.
3. [freemind](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMind) OpenSource with different forkes, a lot of plugins and a groovy-DSL

Answer (score 0):

[skyrails](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~wyos/skyrails/) is an interesting concept; editing would be done by its command line rather than direct manipulation. The implementation currently handles 10^4 nodes, which isn't a large graph by the normal measure (large graphs now-a-days means you can't fit them easily into 32 bit memory), but the concept exploits innate human 3D navigation skills, so should scale to as large as we can cope with.